# Place column values as row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table as follows:

```
column_name
Mark      
John      
Peter
```

I want the exact below output:

```
(No column name)    c2  c3 
Mark              John  Peter    
NULL              Mark  John
```

I have the query for this:

```
select case when id=11 then c1 else null end,c2,c3 from (
select  t2.column_name c1,t1.column_name c2,t3.column_name c3,
ROW_NUMBER () 
    OVER ( order by t1.column_name ) as id
 from SmartName t1 join SmartName t2 on t1.column_name <> t2.column_name
join SmartName t3
 on t2.column_name <> t3.column_name 
 ) as a
 where a.c1 <>a.c2 and a.c2<>a.c3 and a.c3 <> a.c1  
 and id in(2,11) order by c1
```

Although it works correctly, but it sorts out the thing, I understand its because of ORDER BY in Row count. But is there a way to avoid this sorting while achieving the same above result?

Currently the result is as below:

```
(No column name)    c2  c3
John        Peter       Mark      
NULL    John        Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets, so they do not have an ordering unless specified by a column.  Hence, without an additional column, there is no consistent and accurate way to do what you want.

You can tell SQL Server that you don't really want a sort for `row_number()`.  You can do this with:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( order by (SELECT NULL) ) as id
```

This doesn't say "don't do the sort".  Instead, it gives a constant value (unfortunately, SQL Server does not allow a constant for the `order by` without the `select`).

This *may* solve your problem.  There is no guarantee that the rows enumerated by `row_number()` will be in the order that you want.  The *only* way to guarantee a particular order is to use `order by` with a valid column or expression.  But, it *may* do what you want.

Comment: Gordon, thank you, but it does something else :( I mean, the NULL starting row comes as 1st row. Then comes the actual 1st row in my output above. I mean rows are interchanged.

Comment: @Divine . . . Like I said, you need a column to specify the ordering.